# Why don't UI elements reflect their state in Button Click event handler?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, event-handling

In the following example, how can I get:

- the button to be "disabled-grey"
- the message to say "working..."

***while*** the work is being done, not ***after*** the work is done?

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="TestIsEnabled8938.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <StackPanel Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left">

        <Button x:Name="Button_Refresh" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"  
                    DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
                    Content="Refresh" 
                    Click="Button_Refresh_Click" 
                    Height="25" 
                    Width="200"/>

        <TextBlock x:Name="Message" Text="Button is ready to click."/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**code-behind:**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Threading;

namespace TestIsEnabled8938
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Refresh_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Message.Text = "working...";
            Button_Refresh.IsEnabled = false;

            //do work
            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            Message.Text = "Button is ready to click again.";
            Button_Refresh.IsEnabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

#### This doesn't work either:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { Message.Text = "working..."; }));
Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { Button_Refresh.IsEnabled = false; }));
```

## Answer:

Thanks Heinzi, this code works:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Threading;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace TestIsEnabled8938
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker;

        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();

            backgroundWorker.DoWork += (sender, args) =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
            };

            backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, args) =>
            {
                Message.Text = "button is ready to click again";
                Button_Refresh.IsEnabled = true;
            };
        }

        private void Button_Refresh_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Message.Text = "working...";
            Button_Refresh.IsEnabled = false;
            backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the UI to update (and stay responsive) while your task is running, you need to use a separate thread, for example by using a `BackgroundWorker`.

Code example (untested):

```
BackgroundWorker bwButtonWorker;

public Window1() {
    InitializeComponent();

    bwButtonWorker = new BackgroundWorker();

    bwButtonWorker.DoWork += (sender, args) => {
        // do your lengthy stuff here -- this happens in a separate thread
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }

    bwButtonWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, args) => {
        // this happens in the UI thread, so you can modify your UI elements here
        Message.Text = "Button is ready to click again.";
        Button_Refresh.IsEnabled = true;
    }
}

private void Button_Refresh_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Message.Text = "working...";
    Button_Refresh.IsEnabled = false;
    bwButtonWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another method, for what it's worth:-

```
    private void Button_Refresh_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Message.Text = "working...";
        Button_Refresh.IsEnabled = false;

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate(object state)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Message.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate()
               {
                   Message.Text = "Button is ready to click again.";
                   Button_Refresh.IsEnabled = true;
               });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to run your tasks on a  separate thread. One easy way to accomplish is to use the Button.Invoke-method.

[Read more about it here!](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.invoke.aspx)

Comment: Right, I've been trying various Invoke commands but none are working, the one above with Dispatcher compiles but doesn't refresh the UI. Otehrwise I get: System.Windows.Controls.Button' does not contain a definition for 'Invoke' and no extension method 'Invoke' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.Button' could be found.

Comment: In WPF, you have to use Button.Dispatcher.Invoke().  Button.Invoke() is Winforms.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use Control.Invoke() - its internal implementation totally sucks. Invoke() causes one thread to wait for another thread and is therefore likely to introduce deadlocks. You should always use BeginInvoke(), which is non-blocking.